# How to Change code from one .py file to another .py file

Tags: python-3.x

I need to add some code line in a .py file from another .py file

This is the file i want to add code lines:

## Conversor_monedas

```
def menu():
   
    x = int(input("Escoge tu moneda original, siendo:\n1.Dólares\n2.Euros\n3.Soles\n4.Reales\n5.Pesos uruguayos\n6.Pesos Chilenos\n")) #(eeuu,europa,peru,brasil,uruguay,chile)
  
    y = int(input("Escoge tu moneda convertida, siendo:\n1.Dólares\n2.Euros\n3.Soles\n4.Reales\n5.Pesos uruguayos\n6.Pesos Chilenos\n"))
    
    valorx = float(input("Cantidad a convertir: "))
    
    if x == 1:
        dolares(valorx,y)
    if x == 2:
        euros(valorx,y)
    if x == 3:
        soles(valorx,y)
    if x == 4:
        reales(valorx,y)
    if x == 5:
        pesos_uruguayos(valorx,y)
    if x == 6:
        pesos_chilenos(valorx,y)




def dolares(valorx,y):
        
    if y == 2:
        y = "euros"
        valory = valorx*0.89
    elif y == 3:
        y = "soles"
        valory = valorx*3.32
    elif y == 4:
        y = "reales"
        valory = valorx*3.92
    elif y == 5:
        y = "pesos uruguayos"
        valory = valorx*33.81
    elif y == 6:
        y = "pesos chilenos"
        valory = valorx*680.50
        
    print(valorx , "dólares equivalen a ", valory , y)


def euros(valorx,y):
        
    if y == 1:
        y = "dólares"
        valory = valorx*1.12
    elif y == 3:
        y = "soles"
        valory = valorx*3.73
    elif y == 4:
        y = "reales"
        valory = valorx*4.41
    elif y == 5:
        y = "pesos uruguayos"
        valory = valorx*37.97
    elif y == 6:
        y = "pesos chilenos"
        valory = valorx*764.31
        
    print(valorx , "euros equivalen a ", valory ,y)

menu()
```

...and so on with some other function like those two.

I want to add some other function with a new variable that defines another conversion variables from a different .py program that asks me what function I want to include in `Conversor_monedas`.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for help with. Are you wanting to know how you can write a bunch of very similar functions? If so, the usual advice is to not do so, instead you can write just one function and give it more data. For instance, maybe you can pass in a list of exchange rates into a single function that does the conversions. But it's not entirely clear if that's what you're asking about, since you're referring to various .py files and other things, without any clarity on what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

So, this may be way off from what you were thinking, but by entering conversion factors in a file, I believe you can achieve what you're trying to do. Here's a working sample.

```
#! python3
import csv

global ConvDict

def menu():

    BuildCurrencyDict()

    CurrencyList = []
    FromCurrLit = "Escoge tu moneda original, siendo:"
    ToCurrLit = "Escoge tu moneda original, siendo:"
    # \n1.Dólares\n2.Euros\n3.Soles\n4.Reales\n5.Pesos uruguayos\n6.Pesos Chilenos\n")) #(eeuu,europa,peru,brasil,uruguay,chile
    for i, Currency in enumerate(ConvDict):
        FromCurrLit = FromCurrLit + "\n" + str(i+1) + ". " + Currency
        ToCurrLit = ToCurrLit + "\n" + str(i+1) +  ". " + Currency
        CurrencyList.append(Currency)

    FromCurrLit = FromCurrLit + "\n"
    ToCurrLit = ToCurrLit + "\n"
    x = int(input(FromCurrLit)) #(eeuu,europa,peru,brasil,uruguay,chile)

    y = int(input(ToCurrLit))

    valorx = float(input("Cantidad a convertir: "))

    ConvFactor = float(ConvDict[CurrencyList[x-1]][CurrencyList[y-1]])
    valory = valorx * ConvFactor

    print(valorx , CurrencyList[x-1], "equivalen a", valory , CurrencyList[y-1])


def BuildCurrencyDict():
    global ConvDict

    CurrTypes= []
    ConvDict = {}
    # Put a matrix of currencies in CurrConv.txt
    with open('CurrConv.txt') as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
        for LineIn in data:
            # user_info[name] = {'code': code, 'name': name, 'id': id}
            for i, Item in enumerate(LineIn):
                if data.line_num == 1:
                    if i == 0:
                        continue
                    else:
                        CurrTypes.append(Item)
                else:
                    if i == 0:
                        FromCurr = Item
                    else:
                        if i == 1:
                            ConvDict[FromCurr] = {CurrTypes[i-1]:Item}
                        else:
                            ConvDict[FromCurr][CurrTypes[i-1]] = Item

    # print(ConvDict["Euro"]["Dollar"]) # Testing Code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu()
```

CurrConv.txt looks like this. I used tab delimited, but you could use semi-colons or some other delimiter if you wanted to. Line 1 starts with a tab. Then there are tabs between values. Simply add other currencies to the file and they will be added to your conversion prompts.

```
    Euro    Dollar  Yen
Euro    1   1.12    124.53
Dollar  0.89    1   110.88
Yen 0.008   0.009   1
```